# Page break in Angular with Chartjs and tables

Tags: angular, chart.js, page-break, page-break-inside

I have this html where `app-sales-by-category-total` is a component using chartjs. This has multiple charts since it's in a for loop.

```
<div class="sales-cat-total">
  <h2>Sales By Category Total</h2>
  <div class="app-wrapper">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let division of categoryTotalData.divisions">
        <div class="category-tag">
          <div class="cat-item division" [ngStyle]="setBgColor(division.name)">
              <app-sales-by-category-total [month]="categoryTotalData.months" [division]="division"></app-sales-by-category-total>
          </div>
        </div>          
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

Page break won't work. This is my css

```
.app-wrapper,
.sales-cat-total {
    page-break-after: always; 
    page-break-inside: avoid; 
    -webkit-region-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid-page;
}
```

This is the ouput

[image]

Even in tables, page break doesn't seem to work at all with this css:

```
table {
    page-break-inside: auto;
}

tr {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hey you can add br tag

```
    <ng-container *ngFor="let division of categoryTotalData.divisions">
            <div class="category-tag">
              <div class="cat-item division" [ngStyle]="setBgColor(division.name)">
                  <app-sales-by-category-total [month]="categoryTotalData.months" [division]="division"></app-sales-by-category-total>
              </div>
            </div>   
            </br>       
        </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to [ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation). In order to change the view of child you need to use [ng-deep](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) pseudo-class

```
app-sales-by-category-total ::ng-deep {
  table {
    // Style goes here
  }
}
```